# View Complete WCF response on error using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, visual-studio-2010, debugging, configuration

In Visual Studio 2010 I get an error which tells me the first 1024 bytes of a response from a `WCF` service when consumed, but no more.

I would really like to see the entire response so I can work out what is going wrong, where can I get this info from? Is there a way of logging the full text of an error or are they all limited by the 1024 byte rule?

How to View more than 1024 bytes of a wcf response when an error occurs in Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: Use Fiddler to see the full response

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing this in debugging mode, where you have the exact steps pre-identified - you could try if setting [`maxReceivedMessageSize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/wshttpbinding) to a large value helps.

As the description says on the docs:

> maxReceivedMessageSize
>
> A positive integer that specifies the maximum message size, in bytes,
>   including headers, that can be received on a channel configured with
>   this binding. The sender of a message exceeding this limit will
>   receive a SOAP fault. The receiver drops the message and creates an
>   entry of the event in the trace log. The default is 65536.

In your case, it might have been set to a lower value.

You could also check if the `maxBufferPoolSize` has been set correctly - it seems that only one buffer worth of 1024 bytes are being transmitted back, which is possible if someone set the pool size as 1 instead of default 512.